# Different reaction on Filling Excel Cells via D2010 and D10.4 (

Tags: excel, delphi

Here source code  which good work when on D2010, but not Force recalc, when compiled on D10.4 (used same Computer and ExcelApp) :

```
...
CoInitialize(nil);
...
xls := CreateOleObject('Excel.Application')
...   
For I := ...
For J := ...

  if VarIsStr(xls.Cells[I,J].Value) then
       begin
         CellText := xls.Cells[I,J].Value;
         if CellText='AAAA' then xls.Cells[I,J].Value:='CCCC';
         if CellText='BBB' then xls.Cells[I,J].Value:='DDD';
       end;
...
```

also i m open "ExcelFile" with Cells:

```
A1 filled AAAA
B1 filled BBB
and presents Formula in other Cell, 
like  =Concatenate(A1;" / "; B1) (only in another locale)
```

I will see the result CCCC / DDD with app, compiled on 2010
and result AAAA / BBB with app, compiled on D10.4 , but if i go(enter) to the cell with Formula, displayed data will  be Ok

Please, I need some ideas why there is such a difference... or how to force recalc

Comment: Please provide a complete [mre] that we can test with.

Comment: I don't see why it would behave differently depending on the Delphi version, but one way to force Excel to do a recalculation is to set ExcelSheet.EnableCalculation := False followed by ExcelSheet.EnableCalculation := True.